# Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec was not found

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-lzo

Trying to run a mapreduce job with compression

```
hadoop jar \
  /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar \
  randomtextwriter \
  -Ddfs.replication=1 -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec \
  /tmp/randomtextwriter
```

Using parcels distributed lzo to all nodes in the cluster. Even then I am gettin the below error

```
Getting below error 
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec was not found.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.getOutputCompressorClass(FileOutputFormat.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getSequenceWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:56)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:659)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.getOutputCompressorClass(FileOutputFormat.java:138)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution you can manually add the hadoop-lzo jar in the hadoop classpath .

```
curl https://maven.twttr.com/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.19/hadoop-lzo-0.4.19.jar 

hadoop jar \ /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar \ randomtextwriter \ -Ddfs.replication=1 -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true -Dmapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec \ /tmp/randomtextwriter --libjars hadoop-lzo-0.4.19.jar
```

Please make sure you download the compatible version of hadoop-lzo with your hadoop version.

Comment: Hi, It worked. Just need to add --libjars hadoop-lzo-0.4.19.jar before the output directory. Can you please tell me how to add these permanently without using libjars ?

Comment: You can add this jar to the hadoop classpath